# How can I prevent expression duplication in a SELECT MySQL query, by naming or storing the expression?

Tags: mysql

Take this timesheet example, which works fine:

```
SELECT 
    IF(t.start_time >= "2016-01-01", 36.00, 34.50) AS `rate`,
    SUM(ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.stop_time, t.start_time))/3600, 2)) AS `hours`,
    FORMAT(SUM(IF(t.start_time >= "2016-01-01", 36.00, 34.50) * FORMAT(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.stop_time, t.start_time))/3600, 2)), 2) AS `amount`
FROM `timekeeping` t
GROUP BY `rate`
```

What I'm after is to not have to duplicate code, so something like this:

```
SELECT 
    IF(t.start_time >= "2016-01-01", 36.00, 34.50) AS `rate`,
    SUM(ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.stop_time, t.start_time))/3600, 2)) AS `hours`,
    FORMAT(`rate` * `hours`, 2) AS `amount` // <---
FROM `timekeeping` t
GROUP BY `rate`
```

That won't work, but how would I make it work?  I'm assuming some form of sub-query?  Or is it better performance to keep it as one flat query?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your query, but this is how you would rewrite it with a subquery:

```
select rate, hours, FORMAT(rate * hours, 2) AS amount
from (
   select
      IF(t.start_time >= "2016-01-01", 36.00, 34.50) AS rate,
      SUM(ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.stop_time, t.start_time))/3600, 2)) AS hours
   from timekeeping t
   group by rate
) t
```

Comment: Thanks, seems too obvious now that I see it.  I just don't like code duplication.